# KeepAlive on or off for a server handling almost exclusively a single request per client?

Tags: apache-2.4, high-load

The Apache in question is running on a Ubuntu-EC2 instance. It basically handles about a million requests per hour. Essentially a client will `POST` a JSON and that's it - so an interaction of a client with the server only consists of this single request.

My naive assumption would be to turn `KeepAlive` to `off` then. Though I read that keeping a connection alive is also of benefit if the received requests across clients are very similar.

Should I switch `KeepAlive` `on` or `off`?

(And as w're already at it - I would also appreciate a suggestion/clarification on `MaxKeepAliveRequests` and `KeepAliveTimeout`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it off, I would say. If you enable KeepAlive, you'll see lots more Apache processes hanging around than without it.

Also make sure you decrease the `TimeOut` value from the default 300 seconds to a much lower value, to 10 seconds or so.

Answer (score 0):

A quantifiable approach to this question is by logging requests and for each the "number of keepalive requests handled on this connection" (`%k`) [1](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html).

The higher the share of requests featuring a `0` (as it is in my case) the more likely it is that switching `KeepAlive` `off` will be beneficial.